# match non-numbers except forward slash using sed

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I know I can match non-numbers using:

sed 's/[^0-9]//g'

but how can I match non-numbers except forward slashes?

Thank you in advance.

~Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I match non-numbers except forward slashes?

I find it easier to think about this when I rephrase the problem like so:

> how can I match everything except numbers and forward slashes?

To do this, just add the forward slash to the character class:

```
sed 's/[^0-9/]//g'
```

This is saying that you want to match everything except digits and forward slashes.

Comment: `sed` character class really is different from other languages which also uses `/` as delimiter. `[\/]` in sed will match `/` or ``\``.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
sed 's/[^0-9/]|//g'
```

Comment: Your initial answer seems correct? This one will match forward slash, not except.

Comment: I think you can check my comment to NPE's answer. `/` in character class doesn't have to be escaped in sed. If you "escape" it, you will end up adding ``\`` into the character class.